# rolling means by group

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, zoo

I am trying to make rolling means on data that is grouped (`dplyr::group_by`) - I can not get the reason why this cannot work:

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(a=sample(LETTERS[1:2], replace= T, 10),
                 b=rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors = F)
df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(rollapply(b, 3, mean))
```

I can see that a lengthy solution is to be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044493/r-rolling-moving-avg-by-group)  but was wondering why the above does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the `NA` are removed, so we need to use the `fill`

```
 df %>% 
   group_by(a) %>% 
   mutate(newcol = rollapply(b, 3, mean, fill = NA))
```